# Ruby: Get last character from user input

Tags: ruby

So I'm trying to find the last character from user input in Ruby.

I've tried the following-

```
print "Enter in a string: "
user_input = gets
end_char = user_input[-1,1]
puts "#{end_char} is the last char!"
```

But it returns
 " is the last char!".
I've tried

```
end_char = "test"[-1,1]
```

and that works as it should (returns t). But its not working when I use user input as the string instead of just typing in a string itself. Help?

Comment: `chomp` is normally used, but the most direct way is simply `gets[-2]]`.

Answer (score 6):

So when you say "Enter in a string" and you type "foo", what's the last thing you do? Well you hit enter obviously!  So what you actually capture is `"foo\n"`.

Calling `user_input[-1,1]` actually gives back the `\n` return symbol which just prints a break return in the output.

```
print "Enter in a string: "
user_input = gets.chomp
end_char = user_input[-1,1]
puts "#{end_char} is the last char!"
```

the [#chomp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-chomp) method actually removes the return character from the input.

Now when I run it:

```
stacko % ruby puts.rb
Enter in a string: hi Lupo90
0 is the last char!
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this IRB session:

1. I'll enter "foo":

   ```
   irb(main):001:0> user_input = gets
   foo
   "foo\n"
   ```

   I entered "foo", and to terminate the input I had to press <kbd>Return</kbd> (or <kbd>Enter</kbd> depending on the OS and keyboard), which is the "\n" (or "\r\n") line-ending, depending on whether your OS is *nix or Windows.
2. Looking at what I entered:

   ```
   irb(main):002:0> user_input[-1]
   "\n"
   ```
3. Here's what is output. Notice that the single-quotes are on separate lines because a "\n" is a new-line character:

   ```
   irb(main):003:0> puts "'\n'"
   '
   '
   nil
   ```

   (The trailing `nil` is the result of `puts` and isn't important for this example.)

So, `gets` returned everything entered, including the trailing new-line. Let's fix that:

```
irb(main):004:0> user_input = gets.chomp
foo
"foo"
irb(main):005:0> user_input[-1]
"o"
irb(main):006:0> puts '"%s" is the last char' % [user_input[-1]]
"o" is the last char
```

`chomp` is used to strip trailing line-end from the end of a string:

```
irb(main):010:0> "foo\n".chomp
"foo"
irb(main):011:0> "foo\r\n".chomp
"foo"
```

This is a [really common question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bruby%5D%20gets%20chomp) on Stack Overflow. Perhaps searching for it would have helped?