# In my Ruby Code, Why does my variable inside a string produce a new line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, variables, interpolation

Ok so this is my first day learning and I was trying to create a very basic questionnaire with Ruby.

For example, this would be my code:

```
print "What is your name? "
name = gets
puts "Hello #{name}, Welcome."

print "What year were you born in?"
year =  2014
year1 = gets.chomp.to_i
year2 = year-year1
puts "Ok. If you were born in #{year1}, then you are probably #{year2} years old."
```

Now if I input "Joe" for my name and "1989" for my birthdate, it would give me the following lines...

> Hello Joe
>   , Welcome.
>
> Ok. If you were born in 1989, then you are probably 25 years old.

I'm really confused about what's so different about the two strings.

Comment: I just answered a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110650/ruby-get-last-character-from-user-input/27110871#27110871)

Answer (score 3):

You've got the right idea with the way you're processing the year that the user inputs. When they type "Joe" at the prompt, this results in the string value "Joe\n" getting assigned to the `name` variable. To strip newlines off the end of the string, use the `chomp` method. This would change the line to `name = gets.chomp`.

You might also want to explicitly convert the input to a string. If the user ends the input with control-D, `gets` will return `nil` instead of the empty string, and then you'll get a `NoMethodError` when you call `chomp` on it. The final code would be `name = gets.to_s.chomp`.

Comment: Thank you! BTW: I just saw that a similar question was asked, I did spend a lot of time trying to find the question and couldn't find anything. Guess I struggled to phrase the question properly. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

When you call "gets" it actually appends the newline character "\n" to the end of the string by default. May I suggest adding the method "chomp" to the end of gets to remove the new line?

New answer:

```
print "What is your name? "
name = gets.chomp
puts "Hello #{name}, Welcome."

print "What year were you born in?"
year =  2014
year1 = gets.chomp.to_i
year2 = year-year1
puts "Ok. If you were born in #{year1}, then you are probably #{year2} years old."
```